# Windows 7 Not Booting After Moving Partition

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop, partitioning

I have a Sony Vaio laptop. After using GParted to move the primary Windows partion, the laptop no longer boots, saying 'Operating system not found'.

I don't have a recovery disc and the only other machine I have access to is a Mac Mini.

I have tried creating a bootable USB using the recovery ISO from Microsoft. I can see all the files on the USB stick from my Mac. I followed the instructions here: http://borgstrom.ca/2010/10/14/os-x-bootable-usb.html

I have set the laptop BIOS boot order to be 'External' first, but the laptop refuses to boot from the USB stick. I have previously been able to boot from a linux installation on the USB stick.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I have now managed to get the laptop to boot into Windows. I used a repair disk (from another version of Windows 7) from my USB stick.

However, once booted it now says 'This copy of Windows is not genuine'.

Is there any way to fix that? The laptop didn't come with a Windows disc.

**UPDATE**

Laptop is now working. The Windows system was appear on the wrong drive letter (E instead of C) and causing it to think Windows was not genuine. I changed drive letters in the registry and problem solved.

Comment: What exactly did you try to do? And what do you mean by "moved primary windows partition"? Did you resize it, split it in half, please specify. and if you can't boot from usb stick, try selecting the flash drive under the bios "hard disk drive boot priority" and selecting the hard drive as first boot device, your usb stick might be recognised as a hard drive, instead of external usb storage.

Comment: I resized it. There was an empty partition of 100 Mb before the Windows partition, so I removed the 100 Mb partition. I then expanded the Windows partition to use up the 100 Mb 'hole'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This small partition you deleted contains the boot manager (file "bootmgr" and folder "/boot/") and these files are missing on the Windows 7 partition, so now you system can't boot.

It is possible to fix this, if you boot from Windows 7 installation DVD, or USB, and select system repair.

This installs the boot manager IN the Windows 7 partition and after this Windows 7 boots fine.

Like I wrote in the comment, if you can't boot from usb stick, try selecting the flash drive under the bios "hard disk drive boot priority" and selecting the hard drive as first boot device, your usb stick might be recognised as a hard drive, instead of external usb storage.